# Execute a statement even if an error occurs

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have this SQL Server 2012 express stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE GetNewCodes
    @gintNewCodes bigint,   
    @presNewCodes tinyint,
    @levelNewCodes bigint,
    @quantityNewCodes smallint
AS

-- Get new codes from INCIC database.
DECLARE @return_value int,
        @xmlGenerated xml,
        @xmlString NVARCHAR(MAX)

SET NOCOUNT ON;

    -- Set that this stored procedure is running
    update dbo.RunningSPs with (serializable) set conf_value = 1
    where sp_name = N'GetNewCodes'

    if @@rowcount = 0
    begin
        insert dbo.RunningSPs(sp_name, conf_value) values (N'GetNewCodes', 1)
    end

EXEC    @return_value = [INCIC].[dbo].[ReadCodeBuffer]
        @gint = @gintNewCodes,
        @pres = @presNewCodes,
        @level = @levelNewCodes,
        @quantity = @quantityNewCodes,
        @xmlGenerated = @xmlGenerated OUTPUT

SET @xmlString = cast(@xmlGenerated as nvarchar(max))

EXEC dbo.ProcessCodes @XmlString = @xmlString

    update dbo.RunningSPs with (serializable) set conf_value = 0
    where sp_name = N'GetNewCodes'

GO
```

And I want to execute ALWAYS this:

```
    update dbo.RunningSPs with (serializable) set conf_value = 0
    where sp_name = N'GetNewCodes'
```

even if I get an error.

**How can I do it?**

Comment: Have you looked at TRY, CATCH?  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms175976.aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
BEGIN TRY

    -- Actual code gets here

END TRY
BEGIN CATCH

    -- Log error (if case)

END CATCH

-- Always executing code
update dbo.RunningSPs with (serializable) set conf_value = 0
where sp_name = N'GetNewCodes'
```

Comment: It should be catch by application code. Or you could create a SP that "safely" logs the error. See the ThrowError SP here: http://sqlhint.com/sqlserver/scripts/tsql/code-template-handling-transactions-sql-server-rollback-xact_abort

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to execute a statement if it creates an error. If you wrap statement in `TRY CATCH` block it will catch error but execution of statement will be interrupted

For example the following two code blocks. First one will not return anything but second one will return 5 and also `PRINT` the message.

```
BEGIN TRY
SELECT 5/0
PRINT 'Do something'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

---

```
BEGIN TRY
SELECT 5/1
PRINT 'Do something'
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```